# In R data.table multiplication by column name based on values of another column

Tags: r, data.table

I want to convert some prices in different currencies to a specific currency.
Suppose I have this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(100)
DT <- data.table(day=1:10, price=runif(10), currency=c("aud","eur"), 
                 aud=runif(10) + 1, eur=runif(10) + 1.5)
DT
    day        price currency      aud      eur
 1:   1   0.30776611      aud 1.624996 2.035811
 2:   2   0.25767250      eur 1.882166 2.210804
 3:   3   0.55232243      aud 1.280354 2.038349
 4:   4   0.05638315      eur 1.398488 2.248972
 5:   5   0.46854928      aud 1.762551 1.920101
 6:   6   0.48377074      eur 1.669022 1.671420
 7:   7   0.81240262      aud 1.204612 2.270302
 8:   8   0.37032054      eur 1.357525 2.381954
 9:   9   0.54655860      aud 1.359475 2.049097
10:  10   0.17026205      eur 1.690291 1.777724
```

The price of every day is expressed in the respective currency shown in the currency column. So 0.30776611 on first day is in AUD (Australian Dollars), and 0.25767250 in EUR (Euro). Columns `aud` and `eur` show the exchange rates of the respective currencies in dollars. How do I create a new price column expressed in dollars in a `data.table` way?

I need to multiple `price` by the appropriate column name based on `currency` in order to obtain this:

```
DT
    day        price currency      aud      eur price.in.usd
 1:   1   0.30776611      aud 1.624996 2.035811    0.5001187
 2:   2   0.25767250      eur 1.882166 2.210804    0.5696634
 3:   3   0.55232243      aud 1.280354 2.038349    0.7071682
 4:   4   0.05638315      eur 1.398488 2.248972    0.1268041
 5:   5   0.46854928      aud 1.762551 1.920101    0.825842
 6:   6   0.48377074      eur 1.669022 1.671420    0.8085841
 7:   7   0.81240262      aud 1.204612 2.270302    0.9786299
 8:   8   0.37032054      eur 1.357525 2.381954    0.8820865
 9:   9   0.54655860      aud 1.359475 2.049097    0.7430328
10:  10   0.17026205      eur 1.690291 1.777724    0.3026789
```

So for the 1st day I multiplied `price * aud = 0.30776611 * 1.624996`, because price was in `aud` in the `currency` column, while on the 2nd `price * eur = 0.25767250 * 2.210804` for the same reason.

The real data include around 40 currencies and thus multiple `ifelse()` creating an arrow anti-pattern are not very convenient.

For the moment, with a subsample of my data, I have this:

```
DT.all[, price := ifelse(curcdd=="AUD", adj.price * AUD, 
                       ifelse(curcdd=="BEF", adj.price * BEF, 
                              ifelse(curcdd=="BGN", adj.price * BGN, 
                                     ifelse(curcdd=="CHF", adj.price * CHF, 
                                            ifelse(curcdd=="CZK", adj.price * CZK, 
                                                   ifelse(curcdd=="DEM", adj.price * DEM, 
                                                          ifelse(curcdd=="EUR", adj.price * EUR, 
                                                                 ifelse(curcdd=="FRF", adj.price * FRF, 
                                                                        ifelse(curcdd=="GBP", adj.price * GBP, 
                                                                               ifelse(curcdd=="ILS", adj.price * ILS, 
                                                                                      ifelse(curcdd=="JPY", adj.price * JPY, 
                                                                                             ifelse(curcdd=="NLG", adj.price * NLG, 
                                                                                                    ifelse(curcdd=="NOK", adj.price * NOK, 
                                                                                                           ifelse(curcdd=="PLN", adj.price * PLN, 
                                                                                                                  ifelse(curcdd=="SEK", adj.price * SEK,
                                                                                                                         ifelse(curcdd=="SGD", adj.price * SGD,
                                                                                                                                ifelse(curcdd=="USD", adj.price, NA)))))))))))))))))]
```

which works, but it's only about 20 currencies, and doing all of them (~40) is certainly not elegant...

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think this will work better if you leave the prices and coversion tables separate. Presumably you got the conversion tables and then merged based on date and currency, right?

Comment: Exactly. I had a price `data.table` and a currency `data.table` and then I merged them with `merge(DT, curDT)`. So we reach the same table with: `DT <- data.table(day=1:10, price=runif(10))`, `currency.DT <- data.table(day=1:10,  currency=c("aud","eur"), aud=runif(10) + 1, eur=runif(10) + 1.5)`, `setkey(DT, day); setkey(currrency.DT, day)`, `DT <- merge(DT, currency.DT)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edit] Working with the idea of using `get` to pull in values referenced by column names that I saw in an answer from Matthew Dowle this seems to be effective:

```
 setkey(DT, currency)
 DT[ , cvt :=  .SD[, get(currency)]*price, by=currency]
 DT

    day      price currency      aud      eur       cvt
 1:   1 0.30776611      aud 1.624996 2.035811 0.5001188
 2:   3 0.55232243      aud 1.280354 2.038349 0.7071681
 3:   5 0.46854928      aud 1.762551 1.920101 0.8258420
 4:   7 0.81240262      aud 1.204612 2.270302 0.9786301
 5:   9 0.54655860      aud 1.359475 2.049097 0.7430328
 6:   2 0.25767250      eur 1.882166 2.210804 0.5696634
 7:   4 0.05638315      eur 1.398488 2.248972 0.1268041
 8:   6 0.48377074      eur 1.669022 1.671420 0.8085842
 9:   8 0.37032054      eur 1.357525 2.381954 0.8820863
10:  10 0.17026205      eur 1.690291 1.777724 0.3026789
```

Here's one method although it doesn't generalize well to larger number of currencies:

```
DT[ , cvt := ifelse (currency == 'aud', price*aud, price*eur) ]
> DT
    day      price currency      aud      eur       cvt
 1:   1 0.30776611      aud 1.624996 2.035811 0.5001188
 2:   2 0.25767250      eur 1.882166 2.210804 0.5696634
 3:   3 0.55232243      aud 1.280354 2.038349 0.7071681
 4:   4 0.05638315      eur 1.398488 2.248972 0.1268041
 5:   5 0.46854928      aud 1.762551 1.920101 0.8258420
 6:   6 0.48377074      eur 1.669022 1.671420 0.8085842
 7:   7 0.81240262      aud 1.204612 2.270302 0.9786301
 8:   8 0.37032054      eur 1.357525 2.381954 0.8820863
 9:   9 0.54655860      aud 1.359475 2.049097 0.7430328
10:  10 0.17026205      eur 1.690291 1.777724 0.3026789
```

You get a warning (and different results if you try wit `if(.){.}else{.}` with:

```
DT[ , cvt := if (currency == 'aud'){price*aud}else{price*eur}]
```

This is completely analogous to what happens with data.frames. But ... using `ifelse` in data.table is known to be slow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I should have noticed that I have more than 20 currencies, so I 'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, you need to specify the number of different currency (in this case `2`) and the number of observations (in this case `10`), and it is also assumed that the currency values (`'aud','eur'` etc) are last a few columns.

```
> B_msk <- matrix(rep(DT$currency,2), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)==matrix(rep(colnames(DT)[-(1:3)], 10), ncol=2)
> DF <- data.frame(DT)
> DF$in_USD <- rowSums(DF[colnames(DT)[-(1:3)]]*B_msk*DF$price)
> DF #or data.table(DF)
   day      price currency      aud      eur    in_USD
1    1 0.30776611      aud 1.624996 2.035811 0.5001188
2    2 0.25767250      eur 1.882166 2.210804 0.5696634
3    3 0.55232243      aud 1.280354 2.038349 0.7071681
4    4 0.05638315      eur 1.398488 2.248972 0.1268041
5    5 0.46854928      aud 1.762551 1.920101 0.8258420
6    6 0.48377074      eur 1.669022 1.671420 0.8085842
7    7 0.81240262      aud 1.204612 2.270302 0.9786301
8    8 0.37032054      eur 1.357525 2.381954 0.8820863
9    9 0.54655860      aud 1.359475 2.049097 0.7430328
10  10 0.17026205      eur 1.690291 1.777724 0.3026789
```

---

## Edit:

Hope this solution solves memory issue, (but still need to have the data in a `data.frame`)

```
> Idx=cbind(1:10,match(DT[,currency], colnames(DT))) #replace 10 with the actually np. of obs.
> DF=data.frame(DT)
> DF
   day      price currency      aud      eur
1    1 0.30776611      aud 1.624996 2.035811
2    2 0.25767250      eur 1.882166 2.210804
3    3 0.55232243      aud 1.280354 2.038349
4    4 0.05638315      eur 1.398488 2.248972
5    5 0.46854928      aud 1.762551 1.920101
6    6 0.48377074      eur 1.669022 1.671420
7    7 0.81240262      aud 1.204612 2.270302
8    8 0.37032054      eur 1.357525 2.381954
9    9 0.54655860      aud 1.359475 2.049097
10  10 0.17026205      eur 1.690291 1.777724
> DF$price*as.numeric(DF[Idx]) #assign it as 'DF$P_in_USD'
 [1] 0.5001187 0.5696634 0.7071682 0.1268041 0.8258420 0.8085841 0.9786299 0.8820865 0.7430327 0.3026789
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I liked pretty much creating a mask matrix. However the observations are so many (over 1 million), that I am encountering memory allocation problems. :( I am wondering if there is a way to just `lookup` the appropriate column based on the currency value in a `data.table` way....

Comment: You are welcome. See if the new solution can fit in your RAM.

Comment: It fits, thank you! However `data.table()`'s `get()` is much faster. The mask idea is something I will not forget. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered simply looping over the currencies, filtering the main dataframe to only keep prices in a given currency, performing the conversion in the subset dataframe and finally stacking all currency dataframes (or progressively fill a column in the main dataframe)